# Formatting search queries from Civi

Tags: wordpress, profile, php, css

Can anyone tell me where I can find the php or css that affects how search profiles are formatted? I want to alter how it looks on the webpage because it clashes with the flow of the website. Any suggestions on a plugin that allows you to search and pull contact information from civi is also appreciated! Thank you very much for your time!